# How to show that smallest value of $x(x-a)$ (if $0\leq x\leq a$) is when $x=\frac{a}{2}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to show that smallest value of $x(x-a)$ is when $x=\frac{a}{2}$?
$0\leq x\leq a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: $$x(x-a)=x^2-ax=x^2-2\cdot x\cdot \frac{a}{2}+\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2=\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 \ge \, ??$$

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use AM-GM inequality as
$$x(a-x) \le \left(\frac{x+a-x}{2}\right)^2=\frac{a^2}{4} \implies \color{red}{x(x-a)\ge -\frac{a^2}{4}}.$$
Here, the equality holds when $x=a-x \implies x=a/2$.

Answer (score 1):

the minimum value of the parabola $A x^2+B x+C$ for $A>0$ is at its vertex  $-\frac{B}{2A}.$

So, in our case we have exactly the point $\frac{a}{2}.$

Answer (score 1):

We have the expression $x(x-a)$ with $a \gt 0$.

To answer the OP's question using only elementary mathematics, we first calculate
$\tag 1 x(x-a) = \frac{-a^2}{4} \; \; \text{ when } \; x =\frac{a}{2}$

For any $x \in \mathbb R$, we can write $x = \lambda a$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb R$. So,

$\quad x(x-a) =  \lambda a (\lambda a - a) \gt \frac{-a^2}{4} \; \; \text{ iff}$
$\quad \lambda^2 a^2 -\lambda a^2 \gt \frac{-a^2}{4} \; \; \text{ iff}$
$\quad 4 \lambda^2 - 4 \lambda + 1 \gt 0  \; \; \text{ iff}$
$\quad (2 \lambda - 1)^2 \gt 0  \; \; \text{ iff}$
 
$\quad \lambda \ne \frac{1}{2}$